# How to debug 64-bit applications with Visual Studio Development Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, 64-bit, asp.net-development-serv

I have webservice, that I want to test using webserver from Visual Studio (called Visual Studio Development Server). I'm using VS 2012.

My webservice needs to be 64-bit. I added x64 unmanaged `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` to my project. At this point, all I can see is the yellow error screen with:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I am able to fix that, when I'm deploying to full IIS, but there's a problem in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 is running as 32-bit application, it is impossible to run 64-bit application in it. 
I can only try to use IIS Express.

I select "Use Local IIS Web server", and tick "Use IIS Express" checkbox.

In order to run IIS Express in 64bit with VS2012, you should add the following item to registry:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\WebProjects`

Name: `Use64BitIISExpress`,   Type: `REG_DWORD`,    Value: `1`